# Efficiently compute 3D boundary points given boundary function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

**Background**

In an `a x a x a` cubic, I have a 3D boundary defined by
[image],
where `x`, `y`, and `z` are the 3D coordinates, and `a` is the side length of the cubic, serving as a normalisation constant here.

Given a 3D point `(x, y, z)`, one can substitute it into the function. If the function equals 0, then we know the point is on the boundary. Otherwise, it is not.

**Objective**

Now, I wish to find all the boundary points (with some certain coarseness, of course) with MATLAB and output those points into a `.csv` file.

**Brute-force solution in mind**

I understand that I can set a "coarseness", say `STEP_SIZE = 0.01*a`, and then exhaust the whole space by testing whether the point is on the boundary or not one by one. However, I feel this brutal solution is not elegant at all.

**Question**

Hence, I am looking for a more elegant and efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Do you have the symbolic math toolbox?

Comment: @Schorsch Yes, I have.

Comment: I currently don't have access to Matlab, but could you use that toolbox to obtain a parametric solution for `f=0`?

Comment: @Schorsch I have searched and found a lot of stuff about this. Could you please tell me the name of the function? I have never used that tool box before. Thanks!